# Deep Neural Network Chainer install issue

Tags: python, cython, chainer

Chainer is a 2nd generation of deep learning framework.
When I tried to install it on Win64, Python 2.7, I gor the following message:

Does anybody familiar with Cython understand the potential root cause ?

```
!pip install chainer

Executing cythonize
Options: {'profile': False, 'annotate': False, 'linetrace': False, 'no_cuda': False}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
  File "f:\usertemp\pip-build-apy6xr\chainer\setup.py", line 87, in <module>
    'build_ext': chainer_setup_build.chainer_build_ext,
  File "D:\_devs\Python01\WinPython-64-2710\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "D:\_devs\Python01\WinPython-64-2710\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "D:\_devs\Python01\WinPython-64-2710\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "<string>", line 15, in replacement_run
  File "D:\_devs\Python01\WinPython-64-2710\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 207, in find_sources
    mm.run()
  File "D:\_devs\Python01\WinPython-64-2710\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 291, in run
    self.add_defaults()
  File "D:\_devs\Python01\WinPython-64-2710\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 320, in add_defaults
    sdist.add_defaults(self)
  File "D:\_devs\Python01\WinPython-64-2710\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 130, in add_defaults
    build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
  File "D:\_devs\Python01\WinPython-64-2710\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 312, in get_finalized_command
    cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
  File "D:\_devs\Python01\WinPython-64-2710\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized
    self.finalize_options()
  File "chainer_setup_build.py", line 273, in finalize_options
    distutils.sysconfig.customize_compiler(compiler)
  File "D:\_devs\Python01\WinPython-64-2710\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\distutils\sysconfig.py", line 195, in customize_compiler
    cpp = cc + " -E"           # not always
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Comment: This is in distutils (before it really gets to running cython). Beyond that I don't really know!

Comment: What compiler do you have installed? MSVC or GCC? Have you managed to compile any other Cython modules?